# Aggregating data in seaborn plots using sum function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a layoff dataset with `PeriodIndex` as shown below:

```
        Industry    Laid_Off_Count
Year        
2022-10 Finance 0.0
2022-10 Healthcare  0.0
2022-09 Consumer    600.0
2022-09 Healthcare  113.0
2022-09 Finance 85.0
2020-03 Travel  0.0
2020-03 Transportation  8.0
2020-03 Consumer    6.0
2020-12 Retail  20.0
2020-11 All Others  75.0
1791 rows × 2 columns
```

having unique Industry values as:

```
array(['Finance', 'Healthcare', 'Consumer', 'All Others', 'Food',
       'Transportation', 'Real Estate', 'Retail', 'Travel'], dtype=object)
```

Creating a plot as below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
sns.histplot(data=df_copy3,y='Industry',hue=df_copy3.index.year,ax=ax,multiple='dodge',stat='count')
plt.savefig('Tech layoffs by Industry.jpeg')
```

I'm getting result as

[image].

By default, stat argument is `'count'` function, and other options for `sns.histplot` are `'frequency'`, `'probability'`, `'percent'` and `'density'`. I want to aggregate using `'sum'` function and get a plot that looks like this:

[image: Output]

In short, I want the sum of laid off employees along X-axis grouped by Industry and `hue=df.index.year`.

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe you want to use weights, as in `sns.histplot(...., weights='layoff_count')`?

Comment: Hey, thanks man! This is exactly what I was missing. Worked like a charm.

Comment: `sns.histplot` can be be used, but this is a bar plot, not a histogram. As such, the appropriate method to use is `sns.barplot` with `estimator='sum'`: `sns.barplot(data=df_copy3, y='industry', x='Laid_Off_Count', hue=df_copy3.index.year, estimator='sum', ax=ax)`.